# Tastypie - PUT deletes all unsent (unset) fields in object - UPDATE

Tags: django, tastypie, put

I want to update an object and I'm using Tastypie via the `PUT` method. But all previously set fields which are not reset in my JSON file are deleted/set to empty.

How can I make an update via Tastypie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, pretty easy: Just use `PATCH` :)

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#partially-updating-an-existing-resource-patch